# How to inherit class methods/attributes using setattr without attribute error: '__weakref__' of 'cls' objects is not writable

Tags: python, class, inheritance, attributeerror, weak-references

**The Problem**

I have different data distributions that I would like to parametrize. Each distribution is defined as its own class; in this way, each distribution can share attribute names (such as `pdf` for probability distributions, or `f` otherwise). For sake of example, consider two datasets - one follows the model of a line, while the other follows a normal distribution.  I would like to have a "master" class (for lack of better word), that can inherit the attributes of the selected distribution. I know that I can use `super().__init__()` in the constructor to inherit from a parent class, but I do not know how to do this to inherit from all parent classes. I would prefer to not have classes that represent different distributions to inherit from each other. For this reason, I thought I could use `setattr` for this purpose, but I am getting the following error:

```
line 54, in initialize_model
    setattr(self, attribute, getattr(model, attribute))
AttributeError: attribute '__weakref__' of 'NormalDistribution' objects is not writable
```

**The Question**

What is the weak reference, and why is it not writable? Can my approach be adapted to work, or is there a better way?

**My Attempt**

```
## imports
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

## first distribution
class NormalDistribution():

    def __init__(self):
        self.nparams = 2

    @staticmethod
    def pdf(prms, x):
        return np.exp(- np.square((x - prms[0])/prms[1]) / 2) / (prms[1] * np.sqrt(2 * np.pi))

    @staticmethod
    def get_parameter_guess(x, **kwargs):
        mu, sigma = np.mean(x), np.std(x, **kwargs)
        return (mu, sigma)

## second distribution
class LinearEquation():

    def __init__(self):
        self.nparams = 2

    @staticmethod
    def f(prms, x):
        return prms[0] * x + prms[1]

    @staticmethod
    def get_parameter_guess(x, y):
        dy = y[-1] - y[0]
        dx = x[-1] - x[0]
        m = dy / dx
        b = np.mean([y[idx] - m * x[idx] for idx in (0, -1)])
        return (m, b)

## I want this to inherit methods/attributes
## specified by distribution_model
class DistributionModel():

    def __init__(self, distribution_model):
        self._distribution_model = None
        self.initialize_model(distribution_model)

    @property
    def available_distribution_models(self):
        result = {}
        result['linear equation'] = LinearEquation()
        result['normal distribution'] = NormalDistribution()
        return result

    def initialize_model(self, distribution_model):
        if distribution_model not in list(self.available_distribution_models.keys()):
            raise ValueError("invalid distribution_model: {}".format(distribution_model))
        self._distribution_model = distribution_model
        model = self.available_distribution_models[distribution_model]
        for attribute in dir(model):
            setattr(self, attribute, getattr(model, attribute))
```

To call,

```
Model = DistributionModel('normal distribution')

np.random.seed(327)
prms = (50, 10)
data = np.random.normal(loc=prms[0], scale=prms[1], size=100).astype(int)
x = np.sort(data)
y = Model.f(prms, x)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
plt.close(fig)
```

Comment: Perhaps you should only set attributes that don't start with `__`? The CPython interpreter garbage collector (gc) deletes all objects that no longer have a reference to them (more or less), a `__weakref__` is a reference to an object that the gc does not take in to consideration before it deletes the object

Comment: The docs [regarding](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#dir) `dir` are a little unclear to me. I followed other examples on SO that used `dir`, others used `__dict__`. From your comment, I am assuming that using `dir` to collect the attributes is not correct. What better way would you recommend?

Comment: I would recommend using the `copy` module https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/copy.html#copy.copy

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround that works for my case. Maybe this will be helpful to someone else, but maybe there's a better way?

I added the function below inside of the class defintions of `LinearEquation` and `NormalDistribution`.

```
def get_kwargs(self):
    result = {}
    result['pdf'] = self.pdf
    result['get_parameter_guess'] = self.get_parameter_guess
    return result
```

Then, the function `initialize_model(distribution_model)` inside class `DistributionModel` is changed to the following:

```
def initialize_model(self, distribution_model):
    if distribution_model not in list(self.available_distribution_models.keys()):
        raise ValueError("invalid distribution_model: {}".format(distribution_model))
    self._distribution_model = distribution_model
    model = self.available_distribution_models[distribution_model]
    for key, attribute in model.get_kwargs().items():
        setattr(self, key, attribute)
```